# Show intro-only edits in "Activity" on the Docs dashboard

Tags: feature-request, documentation

I figured I'd try out the new Introduction section and edited one into a few topics. I can find the edit history on [my profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1191259/frank?tab=documentation); but it is not listed [on the tag's dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/data.table?tab=activity).

I'm guessing this is just an oversight, but just in case, here's why the current situation is bad:

- Introductions, like pins, reflect the overall vision for the topic and so are liable to be contentious. For this reason, changes there should be as transparent as possible so folks can talk it over and get on the same page.
- It's confusing to have this inconsistency, with most (all?) other edits showing up in the activity feed, but not this type.