# Documentation feedback: Edit approval

Tags: support, documentation, edits, privileges, approval

With 2000+ SO reps one has the [privilege to edit questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) but Documentation edits require approval. Is this intentional or just because of BETA?

Considering the various contributions here concerning the (low) quality of Documentation edits a minimum requirement is comprehensible. Is there one I haven't reached yet?

If I overlooked an already existing discussion covering this detail I'd be glad to be pointed to it.

Comment: You need a silver or gold tag badge (in the tag of your proposed edit) in order to make edits in Documentation without review. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331663/documentation-update-august-4th

Comment: [related](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339137/should-people-whove-never-asked-or-answered-a-question-for-c-be-allowed-to-revi/339140#339140)

Comment: @DanielNugent The badge requirements there refer solely to edit or approve/reject an edit on a "_tag's documentation_", don't they?

Comment: Look at the first bullet point: `Users with a silver or gold tag badge (from Q&A) will skip review when they make an edit to that tag's documentation`

Comment: @AlonEitan Thanks! That link helped: "_changes proposed by editors with applicable gold and silver tag badges are immediately approved without further review_". I only had/have a bronze tag badge for this question's topic.

Comment: @DanielNugent Yes, but isn't a "[_tag's documentation_](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/3)" different to a _Documentation topic to that tag_?

Comment: @GeroldBroser: What you called "tag's documentation" is properly called a tag wiki.

Comment: @NicolBolas I see (but I didn't call it like that initially ;) Or _tag info_, for that matter, according to the linked page's header, right? As a non-native speaker I misinterpreted the term _tag's documentation_. Thanks for clarifying this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer at [Should people who've never asked or answered a question for C be allowed to review C documentation changes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339137/should-people-whove-never-asked-or-answered-a-question-for-c-be-allowed-to-revi/339140#339140):

> Additionally, changes proposed by editors with applicable gold and silver [tag badges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags) are *immediately* approved without further review, unless the change modifies versions or changes which example is [pinned](https://stackoverflow.com/help/documentation-anatomy).

Or, as Frank commented, at [*Help Center* > *Documentation* > *Proposed Changes*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/documentation-proposed-changes).

I just had a bronze tag badge for a specific tag.

Comment: Or the help file instead of a meta post: http://stackoverflow.com/help/documentation-proposed-changes